# Show only a selection of an image + 'hover move around effect'

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, hover

I'm trying to create a website which works like this. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkIg5.png)  
The website show's only a part of a big image and you can move the picture when you move your mouse over the image ( Mouse to the left -> picture moves to the right)

What is the best way to do it? I also might want to switch between a couple of pictures.

Comment: I would recommend using the jQuery UI plugin and taking advantage of draggable(). Then use opacity, z-index, and fading techniques to achieve what you want. whatever you do, do NOT use the animate function for this solution. I will find you in your sleep. *edited to provide link to demo/docs* http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: that has to be *the* most *ominous* means of giving advice I've ever seen on this site...'find him in his sleep'? ...now *I'm* scared to go to sleep. =/

Comment: Yes. I will find him in his sleep. Awake him; and force him to change his method!

Comment: I'd also bring coffee, but it would be decaf. *sinister laugh*

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, Just out of curiosity, why not animate?  Performance reasons?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: and now I'm having flashbacks to the recent Muppets movie: *maniacal laugh*, *maniacal laugh*, *maniacal laugh*...still, that's more peacable than I was expecting at least. =)

Comment: A friend just showed me this, [link](http://invisiblechildrenstore.myshopify.com/products/kony-kit) - that's almost exactly what I need!

Comment: Yep. Each time you would move a new animation would have to be calculated. jQuery has a function called 'step' which calculates the time it will take to end at the expected place. it takes 17ms to calculate this function each time it's called. Animate would have to be called several times to move to the 'mouse position'. The only way to avoid this would be to only allow for "X" amount of pixels to be traversed, with no dynamic involement. that would basically become a 'slideshow' at that point, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response, you said that [This Link](http://invisiblechildrenstore.myshopify.com/products/kony-kit)

provided the exact functionality that you wanted. Based on that site, this is the code they use to maintain this.

```
// enable the zoominess
  if( image.originalWidth > wrapperWidth ){
    $(settings.activeImageId).width(wrapperWidth).height(wrapperHeight).hover(function(){
      // zoom in
      $(this).addClass('zoomed').width(image.originalWidth).height(image.originalHeight);
      $activeWrapper.mousemove( function(e){
        var localX = ~~(((e.pageX - $activeWrapper.offset().left)/wrapperWidth) * 100);
        var localY = ~~(((e.pageY - $activeWrapper.offset().top)/wrapperHeight) * 100);
        if( localY > 100 ){ localY = 100; }
        var fromLeft = (image.originalWidth - wrapperWidth) * localX/100;
        var fromTop = (image.originalHeight - wrapperHeight) * localY/100;
        //console.log( fromLeft,' :: ', fromTop);
        $(settings.activeImageId).css('left', -fromLeft+'px').css('top', -fromTop+'px');
      });
    },
    function(){
      // zoom out
      $(this).removeClass('zoomed').width(wrapperWidth).height(wrapperHeight);
      $activeWrapper.unbind('mousemove');
    });
  }
}
```

And they use:

```
#active-wrapper .zoomed {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

To control the position of the element.

Comment: Honestly? I have no idea. I know that ~ is a bitwise operator and inverts the bits. What ~~ does is beyond my scope. sorry broham.